# Do some calculation in a text file in shell

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed

I have a text file:

```
$cat ifile.txt
this is a text file
assign x to 9 and y to 10.0702
define f(x)=x+y
```

I would like to disable the original line and divide the x-value by 2 and multiply the y-value by 2

My desired output is

```
$cat ofile.txt
this is a text file
#assign x to 9 and y to 10.0702    
assign x to 5 and y to 20.1404
define f(x)=x+y
```

Here `5 is calculate from 9/2 and rounded to the next integer` and `20.14 is calculated from 10.07x2 and not rounded`

I am thinking of the following way, but can't write a script.

```
if [ line contains "assign x to" ]; then new_x_value=[next word]/2
if [ line contains "and y to" ]; then new_y_value=[next word]x2

if [ line contains "assign x to" ]; 
   then disable it and add a line "assign x to new_x_value and y to new_y_value"
```

Comment: In awk you can use variable NR to check row number and perform the operation. Is this your homework ?  What habve you tried so far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

pat="(assign x to )([[:digit:]]+)( and y to )([[:digit:].]+)"
while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ $line =~ $pat ]]; then
        echo "#$line"
        x2=$(echo "(${BASH_REMATCH[2]} + 1) / 2" | bc)
        y2=$(echo "${BASH_REMATCH[4]} * 2" | bc)
        echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}$x2${BASH_REMATCH[3]}$y2"
    else
        echo "$line"
    fi
done < ifile.txt > ofile.txt
```

Output:

```
this is a text file
#assign x to 9 and y to 10.0702
assign x to 5 and y to 20.1404
define f(x)=x+y
```

- The regex `(assign x to )([[:digit:]]+)( and y to )([[:digit:].]+)` matches
  a literal string, followed by digits, followed by a literal string,
  and followed by digits including decimal point.
- The `bc` command `(${BASH_REMATCH[2]} + 1) / 2` caclulates the `ceiling`
  value of the input divided by 2.
- The next `bc` command `${BASH_REMATCH[4]} * 2` multiplies the input by 2.

The reason I have picked `bash` is just because it supports `back reference` in regex and is easier to parse and reuse the input parameters than `awk`. As often pointed out, `bash` is not suitable for processing large files due to the performance reason. If you plan to large / multiple files, it will be recommended to use other languages like `perl`.

With `perl` you can say:

```
perl -pe 's|(assign x to )([0-9]+)( and y to )([0-9.]+)|
    "#$&\n" . $1 . int(($2 + 1) / 2) . $3 . $4 * 2|ge' ifile.txt > ofile.txt
```

**[EDIT]**

If your ifile.txt looks like:

```
this is a text file
assign x to   9 and y to   10.0702   45
define f(x)=x+y
```

- There are more than one space before the numbers.
- One more value exists at the end (after whitespaces).

Then please try the following instead:

```
pat="(assign x to +)([[:digit:]]+)( and y to +)([[:digit:].]+)( +)([[:digit:].]+)"
while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ $line =~ $pat ]]; then
        echo "#$line"
        x2=$(echo "(${BASH_REMATCH[2]} + 1) / 2" | bc)
        y2=$(echo "${BASH_REMATCH[4]} * 2" | bc)
        y3=$(echo "${BASH_REMATCH[6]} * 2" | bc)
        echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}$x2${BASH_REMATCH[3]}$y2${BASH_REMATCH[5]}$y3"
    else
        echo "$line"
    fi
done < ifile.txt > ofile.txt
```

Result:

```
this is a text file
#assign x to   9 and y to   10.0702   45
assign x to   5 and y to   20.1404   90
define f(x)=x+y
```

The plus sign after a whitespace is a `regex quantifier` and defines the number of repetition. In this case it matches one or more whitespace(s).

Comment: Thank you very much. It helped me. Would you kindly suggest how it will work if there are more than one space after `to`. e.g. `assign x to (3-4 blank spaces) 9 and y to (3-4 blank space)     10.0702`.

And also how to assign one more value. e.g. `assign x to      9 and y to    10.0702    45`. I am trying with this `(assign x to )([[:digit:]]+)( and y to )([[:digit:].]+)([[:digit:].]+)

 and `y3=$(echo "${BASH_REMATCH[4]} * 2" | bc)`

Comment: @Kay thank you for the feedback. I've added another bash code which will work with your additional requirements. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much.. I understood it now. Your script saved my times.. I was just doing manually..

Answer (score 1):

One in awk:

```
awk '
/assign/ {                                          # when assign met in record
    for(i=1;i<=NF-1;i++)                            # iterate from the beginning
        if($i=="to" && $(i-1)=="x")                 # if to x
            $(i+1)=((v=$(i+1)/2)>(u=int(v))?u+1:u)  # ceil of division
        else if($i=="to" && $(i-1)=="y")            # if to y
            $(i+1)*=2                               # multiply by 2
}1' file                                            # output
```

Output:

```
this is a text file
assign x to 5 and y to 20.1404
define f(x)=x+y
```

Sanity checking of the ceiling calculation left as homework...

Comment: Many thanks for your help. Would you please suggest why it is not working if I delete the `assign` word from the ifile.txt

Comment: `/assign/`means that only records with string `assign` in them are processed. If you remove it, all records are searched for `to x` and `to y`.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{if(match($0,/^assign/)){b=$0;split($0,a," ");a[8]=a[8]/2;a[4]=a[4]/2; for (x in a) {c = a[x] " " c; $0 = "#" b "\n" c } } { print }}'
```

Demo :

```
:>awk  ' { if(match ($0, /^assign/)) {b=$0;split($0,a," ");a[8]=a[8]/2; a[4]=a[4]/2; for (x in a) {c = a[x] " " c; $0 = "#" b "\n" c } } { print }}' <ifile
this is a text file
#assign x to 9 and y to 10.0702
to x assign 5.0351 to y and 4.5
define f(x)=x+y
:>
```

Explanation:

```
awk  ' { 
if(match ($0, /^assign/))  <--- $0 is whole input record. ^ is start of line. 
                                 We are checking if record is starting with "assign"

    {b=$0; <-- Assign input value to variable b 
     split($0,a," "); <-- Create a array by splitting input record with space as separator 
     a[8]=a[8]/2; a[4]=a[4]/2; <--  Divide value stored in 8 and 4 index
     for (x in a)  <-- Loop for getting all values of array 
          {c = a[x] " " c; <-- Create a variable by concatenating values of a   
     $0 = "#" b "\n" c <-- Update value of current record. "\n" new line operator 
    } } 
{ print }}'
```